# Insert into table variable using result set from a UDF

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a UDF which takes a comma separated list and turns it into rows
So the output of

```
select * from fnDrugSplit('one,two,three',',')
```

would be

```
one
two
three
```

When I try to insert these results into a table variable with

```
declare @drugName1 table(drugName1 varchar(50),drugName2 varchar(50))
insert into @drugName1(drugName1,drugName2)
values(
         (select * from fnDrugSplit('one,two,three',',')
        ,(select * from fnDrugSplit('one,two,three',',')
      )
```

I get `Incorrect syntax near ')'`, the last parentheses closing out the `values` block.  The function will is deterministic and I don't know why I'm getting this error because

```
declare @drugName1 table(drugName1 varchar(50),drugName2 varchar(50))
insert into @drugName1(drugName1,drugName2)
values(
         (select 'one')
        ,(select 'two')
      )
select * from @drugName1
```

works fine.  What am I missing here?

The second parameter in the function is the delimiter for rows.  SQL Server 2008

Comment: use a select clause not a values clause.

Comment: Also, even using the values clause the "select" in "select 'one'" is unnecessary.  You can simply say "values ('one','two')".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your udf returns a table with 3 rows.  You can't put 3 rows of 1 column into the table with the "VALUES" clause.  The "VALUES" clause expects scalars, which is why "Select 'one'" and "Select 'two'" work.

You don't need "VALUES" you can just articulate your select.

```
Insert into @drugName1
(drugName1, drugName2)
 select fn.ColName, fn.ColName
 from fnDrugSplit('one,two,three',',') fn
```

Not sure how you want to put 3 values into 2 columns, that wasn't clear in your question.  Also, I don't know what the column name is for your UDF, so I assumed ColName.