# SQL Table Function to variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Function which returns a table. I am wondering how to take the result table and return it into a temporary table I use (Called @Values in this case).

Here is an example:

```
declare @values table(
MinValue money, 
MaxVale money
)


/*
Fill @Values with dbo.GenPayValues function 
*/
```

Currently I am only able to select from the function like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.GenPayValues(13.00, 25.00)
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks so much for taking the time to read this.

Comment: May I ask why the DownVotes and Close votes?

Comment: Possibly because it's a simple question, possibly because [it's been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742434/insert-into-table-variable-using-result-set-from-a-udf), possibly because you haven't demonstrated any research or an attempt to try to perform an insert yourself, and possibly because it had three up-votes in the first two minutes. I can cite hundreds of better questions that don't get three up-votes ever.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the detailed response. I am truly sorry and did not think the question was a violation of any rules. I love the great community support here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work as long as the structures are exactly the same:

```
INSERT @values
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.GenPayValues(13.00, 25.00)
```

However, if the structures are different, do this instead:

```
SELECT *
INTO #values
FROM dbo.GenPayValues(13.00, 25.00)
```

That will create a temporary table, instead of variable, but it will still be dropped at the end of the scope.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it would be something simple! I Will accept answer when it allows me.

Comment: This kinda violates the "select *" rule.  I would create a @values  with these columns (MinValue money, 
MaxVale money)........and be explicit on the select..........as in.....Insert into @ values (MinValue, MaxValue) Select MinValue , MaxVale from dbo.GenPayValues(0,0) ........  If/when someone changes the table-valued function........it will be found sooner than later.

Answer (score 2):

Just `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO @values
SELECT *
FROM dbo.GenPayValues(13.00, 25.00)
```

*I am assuming that `dbo.GenPayValues` returns data in the same order as you have declared your table `@values` - with no extraneous columns. If not, you can reorder them or select explicitly:*

```
INSERT INTO @values(MinValue, MaxVale)
SELECT MinValue, MaxValue
FROM dbo.GenPayValues(13.00, 25.00)
```